# Selected DropDownList Value Not Sending to ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass the selected value of a DropDownList to a new controller method. However, in the controller, `leagueKey` is always coming back null. The drop down list is populating with values.

If I change `new { leagueKey = Model.SelectedLeagueKey}` to `new {leagueKey = "test"}` the controller correct receives the "test" value. It appears that the DropDownList isn't binding the selected value to `Model.SelectedLeagueKey`.

### Model

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Leagues { get; set; }
public string SelectedLeagueKey { get; set; }
```

### View

```
<div class="edit-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedLeagueKey, new SelectList(Model.Leagues, "Key", "Value", Model.SelectedLeagueKey),"Select League")
</div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Select League", "AddTeam", "Team", new { leagueKey =  Model.SelectedLeagueKey}, null)
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult AddTeam(LTEDContext context, string leagueKey)
    {
        //Do something with leagueKey here
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Why is your view strongly typed yet you're passing in the leagueKey via a query string?

Comment: I'm attempting to pass the leagueKey from one strongly typed view to another. The view listed above is the originating view, while there's a separate view that is strongly typed to another Model that is populated based on the leagueKey that's passed to it.

Comment: you can pass the value as suggested by @fde bellow, and then redirect to another controller function which is returning the other view linked with a different model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view send you the SelectedLeagueKey parameter according to

```
<div class="edit-field">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedLeagueKey, new SelectList(Model.Leagues, "Key", "Value", Model.SelectedLeagueKey),"Select League")
</div>
```

Try to use the next code in a view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddTeam", "Team")) {    
<div class="edit-field">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedLeagueKey, new SelectList(Model.Leagues, "Key", "Value", Model.SelectedLeagueKey),"Select League")
</div>
<submit type="submit"/>
```

}

and the next one in controller:

```
public ActionResult AddTeam(LTEDContext context, string SelectedLeagueKey)
{
    //Do something with leagueKey here
    return View();
}
```